# Adding same ID to same rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem in SQL postgres. I'm starting with this kind of table:

[image: Starting Table]

As you can see, I have some rows with same year, month, day, which can often occur. For each of them the columns count and dmg are different. I want to associate for each of these rows with same year,month,day but different count and dmg, the same number id, as you can see in the next img:

[image: Finished Table]

wish someone could help me. thanks in advance!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by year, month, day) as id,
       t.*
from t;
```